# Understanding benefit of higher watts on power bank

Tags: power, current

I have seen multiple lithium power banks offering 5000mAh.
The Price can increase substantially for the same mAh but a higher output wattage.

My understanding of a 5000mAh battery is that this power bank can output 5000 milliampheres over 1 hour, or roughly 2500 milliampheres over 2 hours - then it will be drained of its energy

Why would I spend an additional $200 for a battery with the same capacity just a higher watt output?

Comment: Assuming that all batteries are EXACTLY the same, connecting batteriesin parallel the total resistance of the bank becomes very low and resistance of cable must be taking into account. This and the ratio of volume and weigth between single and bank sould be taking into account. A fuse per battery it is recomended.

Answer (score 1):

Capacity and wattage are certainly not the same - two batteries could both by 5000 mAh but one could be 12 volt and the other could be 1.5 volts. Clearly the 12 volt battery has 8 times the wattage capabilities on face value.

However, even this may not be true if you dug deeper. A 5000mAh battery may well be able to supply 10 amps for 30 minutes and this would be a bigger wattage than discharging at 5 amps but, a different battery not be be allowed to exceed 5 amp output despite having a 5000mAh rating.

Read the small print in the data sheet. Look at the discharge curves. Compare carefully. Decide on what you need carefully.

Comment: So really my focus should be on what my electrical device needs to consume from the bank, then buy a battery specifically for that? That would be the most efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Li-ion "power banks" are a set of cells with a boost converter that takes the ~3.6V variable of the battery to 5V USB output. In those cases the design and heatsinking of the boost converter limits the current output - you probably won't get 5A out of most of them.

(I'd like to see the $200 one, I suspect that's some sort of super premium product that doesn't need to be that price)